# Phonegap .xap not accepted, get error 1034

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, .net-assembly

I have built an app on build.phonegap.com, so not with the sdk.
I uploaded my custom config.xml file, because I needed the "stay in webview" property for android, the apps works fine in android, but when I try to upload it in the windows phone store I get:

> 1034: The AppManifest.xml file has an invalid entry assembly. Update it and then try again
>
> Make sure the name of the assembly specified in the EntryPointAssembly field in your AppManifest.xaml is the name of a real assembly that exists in your XAP. Rebuilding your project should solve this problem.

I can't access the appmanifest.xml, I tried to rebuild it in phonegap, but it didn't work out for me!

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" version="1.0.0" versionCode="10"   id="com.app" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"> 
<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->
<name>Theappname</name> 
<description> The app. </description> 
<author email="email@adress.com" href="https://aurl.com"> Feel free to contact </author> 
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true"/> </widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on Phonegap's help center today. If you have this problem too, downgrade your app's phonegap version to 1.9.0.